# Alembic 1.8 + DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, alembic

I am now using Alembic 1.8, SQLAlchemy 1.4 and PostgreSQL

I would like to set my FK constraints as "DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE".

I passed the FK options as shown below:

```py
sa.Column(
    "group_id",
    sa.BigInteger,
    sa.ForeignKey(
        "auth_group.id",
        onupdate="CASCADE",
        ondelete="CASCADE",
        deferrable=True,
        initially="IMMEDIATE"
    ),
    index=True,
),
```

It generates my "create table" SQL like this:

```
    CONSTRAINT auth_user_groups_group_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (group_id)
        REFERENCES public.auth_group (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
        DEFERRABLE
```

I expected "DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE" instead of "DEFERRABLE".

Please, let me know how to make the constraint as "DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE".

Thank you.

Comment: `INITIALLY IMMEDIATE` is the default for `DEFERRABLE` as documented [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html). If you use `initially="DEFERRED"` does it render `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED`?

Comment: @GordThompson, Yes! You're correct.

**Nothing shown**: implicitly means NOT DEFERRABLE
**DEFERRABLE**: DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE
**DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED** is only explicitly explained.

Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue (or design choice) of your DDL -> text generator -not with sqlalchemy.

The actual constraint information Postgres uses is stored in the table `pg_catalog.pg_constraint`. If you take a look at the [docs for the pg_constraint table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-constraint.html), you'll notice that the concept of deferability is (v7.2-v15+) controlled entirely by the two boolean columns `condeferrable` and `condeferred`.

Thus, if a constraint is `DEFERRABLE` and it's not `INITIALLY DEFERRED` (checked end of transaction), it can only be `INITIALLY IMMEDIATE` (checked end of statement).

If you want to be absolutely certain, you can run this simple query:

```sql
SELECT
    pgc.conname constraint_name,
    pgc.confrelid::regclass tbl_name,
    CASE
      WHEN pgc.condeferrable
      THEN
        CASE
            WHEN pgc.condeferred
              THEN 'DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED'
              ELSE 'DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE'
            END
      ELSE 'NOT DEFERRABLE'
    END deferrability

FROM
    pg_catalog.pg_constraint pgc

WHERE
    conname = 'auth_user_groups_group_id_fkey'
```

Comment: Alembic(SQLAlchemy)
`deferrable=True, initially="IMMEDIATE",`

CREATE TABLE generated by Alembic

`DEFERRABLE`

The result from your query in pgAdmin4.

`"auth_user_groups_group_id_fkey" "auth_group" "DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE"`

It was a kind of notation issue. Thank you for your query. It's quite helpful to understand the issues.